# SSAS (Tabular) / DAX - Calculate measure over time / Rolling distinct count

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular

I've a question about a rolling distinct count. I'm trying to calculate the latest 30 weeks (210 days) from a specific date (eg. Specific date = 18-02-2019 distinct count from 23-07-2018).

I've found a website/blog where this is explained, https://radacad.com/datesinperiod-vs-datesbetween-dax-time-intelligence-for-power-bi. But in some weird way, my calculation is not working. 
My DAX expression:

```
Aantal mutaties afgelopen 30 weken:= 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(FCT_KlantReis_Mutatie[Mutatie]);
DATESINPERIOD(
   FCT_KlantReis_Mutatie[Mutatiedatum];
    LASTDATE(FCT_KlantReis_Mutatie[Mutatiedatum])  ;-210;DAY)
)
```

But in Excel (and PowerBI) I get the following result:

[image]

The table is linked to a date dimension. My guess is that it must be posible, but how...

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is "FCT_KlantReis_Mutatie[Mutatiedatum]" a field in your fact table, or in a date dimension?

Comment: It is a field in my fact table. Connected to my date dimension.

Comment: you need to use date field from the date dimension instead.

Comment: Thanks! It is working. So simple tiny adjustment.. And it looks so silly I didn't see it. :)